# Seleccionar solo un elemento del recyclerview

Tags: android, recyclerview

Buen día, tengo problemas al tratar de seleccionar solo un elemento del `RecyclerView` anteriormente había implementado una lógica que me selecciona varios elementos pero en esta ocasión necesito que solo me seleccione uno de la lista por ejemplo si yo tengo 3 **items** llamados manzana, pera y fresa si selecciono manzana y luego selecciono pera quiero que manzana se des-seleccione y así sucesivamente mientras voy seleccionando diferentes **items**

Este es el código que tengo para seleccionar varios:

```
if(listaUsuarios.get(position).isSelect() == true){
            listaUsuarios.get(position).setSelect(false);
            arrayList.remove(ObtenerComplementos.nombreOpcion);
            holder.view.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE));
        }
        else{
            listaUsuarios.get(position).setSelect(true);
            arrayList.add(ObtenerComplementos.nombreOpcion);
            holder.view.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.rgb(244,167,29)));
        }
```

"isSelect" y "setSelect" son variables que traigo de mi modelo:

```
public boolean isSelect() {
    return isSelect;
}

public void setSelect(boolean select) {
    isSelect = select;
}
```

Hay alguna forma de adaptar este código y hacer que solo seleccione 1 **item** en lugar de varios, espero me puedan ayudar de antemano muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> en esta ocasión necesito que solo me seleccione uno de la lista

Si deseas seleccionar solo un objeto puedes actualizar la lista para que elimine la selección de todos los elementos excepto del seleccionado, para esto puedes usar este método, el cual recibiría el listado y la posición del elemento:

```
public static List<Usuario> deselectUser(List<Usuario> lstUsuarios, int posicion){
    for(int i = 0; i < lstUsuarios.size(); i++){
        lstUsuarios.get(i).setSelected(false);
    }
    lstUsuarios.get(posicion).setSelected(true);
    return lstUsuarios;
}
```

Al dar clic a el elemento llama el método de esta forma:

```
   lstUsuarios = deselectUser(lstUsuarios, position);
```

de esta forma obtendrás una lista actualizada únicamente con el elemento de la posición.